Natural way to extend the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p^k \mathbb{Z}$ so that the equation $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 (\text{mod }p^k)$ has a solution
We know that for $p \equiv 3 (\text{mod }4)$, there is no solution to $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 (\text{mod }p^k)$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots$, by quadratic reciprocity. But can I embed the ring $\mathbb{Z} / p^k \mathbb{Z}$ in some bigger ring so that it does have a solution? What's the simplest way to do that?
As a related question, if I identify $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z} \cong F_p$ the finite field of $p$ elments, then it seems there is only one quadratic extension field of $F_p$ that contains square roots of all its elements. Are there good references to this result?
The question was inspired by Example 1.6 of Opera de Cribro.

In general, if you have a ring $R$ and you wish to "extend" it by adding roots for a polynomial $P \in R[X]$, the correct ring to consider is $R[X]/(P)$ (the ring $R[X]$ quotiented by the principal ideal $(P)$). However, this notion is more or less well behaved depending on the original ring $R$ and the polynomial $P$.

For a specific $k$, the most natural way is to consider the quotient $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+1)$. Since $x^2+1$ is monic, $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ can indeed be seen as a subring.

A simple way to define your ring is to start with the ring of Gaussian integers and take the congruence modulo $p^k$ on this ring. Or directly, consider the set
$$ 
R = \bigl\{x + iy \mid x, y \in {\Bbb Z}/p^k{\Bbb Z}\bigr\}
$$
equipped with the addition
$$
(x + iy) + (x' + iy') = (x+x') + i (y+y')
$$
and the multiplication
$$
(x + iy) (x' + iy') = (xx' -yy') +i(xy' + x'y)
$$
This is of course equivalent to the constructions proposed in the comments.
